# What part of Solaris version string IDs the update?

Tags: solaris

Solaris 10 server. I need to determine if the server is Solaris 10 Update 9 or greater. Can someone interpret the version strings below? What part of those strings identifies the update that has, or has not, been applied to the server?

```
# uname -a
SunOS rcclab5 5.10 Generic_147440-01 sun4u sparc SUNW,Ultra-80
# cat /etc/release
                   Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10s_u10wos_17b SPARC
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                        Assembled 23 August 2011
```

Comment: You cannot "apply an update" with Solaris 10 and older. You either install a Solaris update from scratch or upgrade an existing installation to a newer Solaris update. What you can apply to an existing installation are patches and patches do not change the Solaris update that is installed and reported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s10s_u10wos_17b` the u<#> is the update version. So that is Solaris 10 Update 10.

Answer (score 7):

The line in `/etc/release` shows it was built in august 2011 and contains `s10s_u10wos_17b` which reads:
Solaris 10 for SPARC (would be `s10x` for `x86`), update 10, "wad of stuff" (just means it's not the initial release), 17th build since `u10` development started, second respin (`b`).

Note that **this doesn't reflect an update that has been applied or not to the server** but the precise version of Solaris that was initially installed on that machine.

Kernel updates can be identified with the kernel patch version, here (`147440-01`) which is the one delivered with `u10`. That means it wasn't updated (patched).

Should you have patched the OS, an additional line would have appeared at the end of the file telling what Solaris update the update match.

Answer (score 0):

Generic_147440-01 shows the level of the kernel being used.  It IS possible to be running an up-to-date kernel w/o having to do an install of the released update by updating keeping current on all the patches.

Answer (score 0):

uname -a shows the Kernel PatchID and the table in this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/solaris_10_kernel_patchid_progression-v2) will show which Solaris 10 update version it us...

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Decoding the update string (e.g. `s10s_u10wos_17b`) is fine for newer update releases, but older and non-update products don't have something in this format in the `/etc/release`.

The Solaris version with month/year (e.g. `Solaris 10 8/11`) is frequently used in documentation and for customer support purposes. You can look up this value in a releases list (e.g. https://trent.utfs.org/wiki/Solaris/Releases) to find what update number it corresponds to (or to find out what other kind of product release it is if it's not an update).